# Create nested Object the short way

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I want this:

1. `var options.server.socketOptions.keepalive = 120;`

Which is known as the **dot notation**.

But it doesn't work, as well known.
So I have to do this:

2. `var options = {};
   options.server = {}
   options.server.socketOptions = {}
   options.server.socketOptions.keepalive = 120;`

I could do instead this:

3. `var options = { server: {socketOptions: {keepalive:120}}}`

Which is the JSON format

But is there any more elegant way using the dot notation instead of the JSON way?

If necessary, I would use a little library which does almost only that.
But I **don't** want to use something like **coffee** or **underscore**.
Preferred I want to know what is possible in the vanilla way

Comment: _var options = { server: {socketOptions: {keepalive:120}}}_ it is the most short way

Comment: The second way is more elegant and readable. And sadly there is no other way to create this other than using bracket notation.

Comment: you may overwriting some other properties/values with you approach (like `option.something` ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in JavaScript only by using the object literals.
However you could use a helper function to construct the object:

```
function build(props, value) {
  return props.split('.').reverse().reduce(function(acc, key, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      acc[key] = value;
      return acc;
    }
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = acc;
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

var options = build('server.socketOptions.keepalive', 120);

console.log(obj); // prints { server: {socketOptions: { keepalive:120 } } }
```

Check [the demo](http://jsbin.com/libocow/4/edit?js,console).